# Azure Pipelines masks ACR Url address with *** in command line tasks

Tags: azure-devops

Basically, I am trying pull some docker images to workspace and run some custom script with those images. My custom script takes docker images as parameters and runs some logic. When I try to run my script I see that Azure Pipelines replaces my ACR login url with ***.

**How to produce?**

- Create a pipeline
- Add Docker login step to download your docker image. (e.g. myacr.io/hello-world)
- Add CMD task which pulls docker image and runs some logic.
- Run your pipeline by passing myacr.io/hello-world
- Echo passed parameter in your script. You will see ***/hello-world

Question: Why is it masking the URL in string which passed to custom script? Is there a way to avoid this behaviour...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the a secret variable?

Comment: It is a service connection..

Comment: Yes, it does. It's a mask, the ACR connection still works fine. What's the question?

Comment: ACR connection works fine.. Problem is I am trying to pass my docker image as a string to script but because of this mask script gets ***/hello-world ...

Comment: Did the *** display in the log? Could you please share a screenshot for it? And share the script here?
If you set a value as secret, then all the words related to this value in this log will be *** .

Comment: @FrankWang-MSFT I'm also in MSFT, having the same issue is the OP.
I'm trying to printout a docker image full path to ADO pipeline log for our developers convenience and I get the masking over the ACR endpoint (which is in no way a secret)